# Google maps is building the map legend visibly under the map, then it pops onto the map, it should just display on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My google map is building correctly but functioning, not in the way I'd like and I'm sure I've implemented the legend incorrectly.

Here is the relevant html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">            
    <div id="map-section" class="panel-body">
        <div id="locationsMap"></div>
        <div id="legend"><h3 class="fw-semibold text-primary-dark text-center">Legend</h3></div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

And the legend css

```
#locationsMap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;    
}

#legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    display:none;
}

  #legend h3 {
      margin-top: 0;
  }

  #legend img {
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

You can visually see the problem here
[F512M Locations Map](https://ferrari-f512m-usa-registry.com/LocationsMap)

The legend is building under the map, and you can see it and then it pops into its desired position. I would much prefer the map displayed itself with the legend already where it belongs.

Here is the code (I only left 5 markers in the data array for brevity, other functions also removed for brevity)

```
'use strict'
 let map;

function locationsMap() {
    // initialize default map, centered in USA
    map = getDefaultMap();
    // initialize info window
    const infoWindow = initializeInfoWindow();
    // vehicleLocation data array
    const vehicleLocations = [
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.63260, -95.59397),
    title: "Car #1 Houston, TX",
    info: ['Rosso Corsa', 'Beige', 'Castoro', 12103]
            },
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.53833, -81.37923),
    title: "Car #2 Orlando, FL",
    info: ['Rosso Corsa', 'Beige', 'Castoro', 22500]
            },
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.612833, -95.582365),
    title: "Car #3 Houston, TX",
    info: ['Rosso Corsa', 'Beige', 'Castoro', 67960]
            },
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.714439, -80.054987),
    title: "Car #4 West Palm Beach, FL",
    info: ['Rosso Corsa', 'Beige', 'Castoro', 20913]
            },
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.099728, -94.578568),
    title: "Car #5 Kansas City, MO",
    info: ['Rosso Corsa', 'Beige', 'Castoro', 4319]
            }
    ];
    // create all markers and info window content
    for (let i = 0; i < vehicleLocations.length; i++) {
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: vehicleLocations[i].position,
                title: vehicleLocations[i].title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: getMarkerImageUrl(vehicleLocations[i].info[0], vehicleLocations[i].info[1]),
                    infoWindow: { content: buildInfoWindowContent(vehicleLocations[i].info, vehicleLocations[i].title) },
                map: map
            });
            // Add a click listener for each marker, and set up the info window.
            marker.addListener("click", () => {
                infoWindow.close();
                infoWindow.setContent(marker.infoWindow.content);
                infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
            });
        }
        // build the map legend
        buildLegend(coloredPins, map);
}


// support functions
function getDefaultMap() {
    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("locationsMap"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 41.23456, lng: -97.87654 },
    });
}
function initializeInfoWindow() {
    return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "",
    disableAutoPan: true
    });
}
```

here is the function that builds the legend itself

```
function buildLegend(pins, map) {
    const urlBase = "https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/ferrari-512m/images/google-map-icons/kraked/";
    const legend = document.getElementById("legend");
    const div = document.createElement("div");

    const innerHTML = `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.rossoBeige.icon}"> ${pins.rossoBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.rossoNero.icon}"> ${pins.rossoNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroBeige.icon}"> ${pins.neroBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroNero.icon}"> ${pins.neroNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroGrigio.icon}"> ${pins.neroGrigio.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.gialloBlu.icon}"> ${pins.gialloBlu.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.gialloNero.icon}"> ${pins.gialloNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.canneBeige.icon}"> ${pins.canneBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.canneNero.icon}"> ${pins.canneNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.maranelloNero.icon}"> ${pins.maranelloNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.metallizatoBeige.icon}"> ${pins.metallizatoBeige.name}<br/>`;

    div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    legend.appendChild(div);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You've yet to explain what the question is?

Comment: I explained it twice, the map legend is building UNDER the map, as in outside the bounds of the map, and then popping into position ON the map. The map should be displaying itself with the legend ALREADY on the map, the user should not see it building itself under the map. If you click the link you will see the behavior

Answer (score 0):

You're already building your element before the map is initialized. The HTML document will of course render your element in that case before the script has had a chance to execute.

```js
function buildLegend(pins, map) {
    const urlBase = "https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/ferrari-512m/images/google-map-icons/kraked/";
    const legend = document.createElement("div");
    legend.id = "legend";
    legend.innerHTML = `<h3 class="fw-semibold text-primary-dark text-center">Legend</h3>`;
    
    const div = document.createElement("div");

    const innerHTML = `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.rossoBeige.icon}"> ${pins.rossoBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.rossoNero.icon}"> ${pins.rossoNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroBeige.icon}"> ${pins.neroBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroNero.icon}"> ${pins.neroNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroGrigio.icon}"> ${pins.neroGrigio.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.gialloBlu.icon}"> ${pins.gialloBlu.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.gialloNero.icon}"> ${pins.gialloNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.canneBeige.icon}"> ${pins.canneBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.canneNero.icon}"> ${pins.canneNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.maranelloNero.icon}"> ${pins.maranelloNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.metallizatoBeige.icon}"> ${pins.metallizatoBeige.name}<br/>`;

    div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    legend.appendChild(div);
    
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
    
    const parent = document.querySelector("#main-container .panel-body");
    parent.append(legend);
}
```

And remove your legend element from the HTML.

Alternatively, change the default display to none, then in the buildLegend function, change it to block.

```js
function buildLegend(pins, map) {
    const urlBase = "https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/ferrari-512m/images/google-map-icons/kraked/";
    const legend = document.getElementById("legend");
    const div = document.createElement("div");

    const innerHTML = `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.rossoBeige.icon}"> ${pins.rossoBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.rossoNero.icon}"> ${pins.rossoNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroBeige.icon}"> ${pins.neroBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroNero.icon}"> ${pins.neroNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.neroGrigio.icon}"> ${pins.neroGrigio.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.gialloBlu.icon}"> ${pins.gialloBlu.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.gialloNero.icon}"> ${pins.gialloNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.canneBeige.icon}"> ${pins.canneBeige.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.canneNero.icon}"> ${pins.canneNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.maranelloNero.icon}"> ${pins.maranelloNero.name}<br/>`
        + `<img src="${urlBase}${pins.metallizatoBeige.icon}"> ${pins.metallizatoBeige.name}<br/>`;

    div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    legend.appendChild(div);
    legend.style.display = "block";    

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answers...Tried version 1, which makes perfect sense, but the legend is not displaying. I even gave the parent div of the map an id and changed the selector and that did not work either. Tried version 2 using <div id="legend"><h3 style="display:none;" class="fw-semibold text-primary-dark text-center">Legend</h3></div> in the html and that displayed the legend but with the same behavior as before

Comment: I'm sure you viewed the source to see the html, but I added the html to the post.